# executeTransaction function's estimated gas limit was not enough to execute the transaction

Tags: gas-limit, out-of-gas, gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

When I executed a transaction with [executeTransaction](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#executetransaction) function then it [failed](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xefcd1993517891805bdb97663f0f059ddd3b52064d4a36c0c8b36eb90e31d7b9) on Ethereum Mainnet due to `out of gas` but when I tried again then it [succeed](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1adfa66619421f01cc28f1323309a7b1f7fb0d9147ea5f33e32591e1e136daba). I compared the gas limits of both the transaction and found that there is no significant difference between them. So, I have the following queries regarding `executeTransaction` function of the Safe Core SDK -

- Why the first gas limit estimation was low which caused the transaction failure?
- what should be done to avoid this to happen again?
- I can see that we can also set gas limit and gas price manually and send to the function as a second argument. So, how one can estimate these values manually and correctly and send them to the function as `options`?

Comment: your transaction reverted with `GS013` and it means the internal transaction failed

Comment: okay, so I think it is an internal transaction fail due to 'out of gas' but I am curious to know why did 'out of gas' occur and how it can be prevented again happening? Please let me know about this.

Comment: most likely the transaction gas limit was too low. The safeTxGas (how much gas is available for the internal transaction) is 0 so the transaction will use all available gas

Comment: okay got it. Although, It is like I was simply calling `executeTransaction` and not setting any value(safeTxHash, gasLimit, gasPrice) manually. Also, this happened for the first time and not sure why the estimated gas limit was low. Thank you again for the quick response. I will try to add handling for this.